# Movie/series taking place most likely in NYC with woman who possesses incredible strength

Tags: story-identification, movie

I remember seeing a clip several years ago of a live action movie where a woman who was walking down a street at night. Then two thugs try to rob or rape her and she tosses the guy nearest to her onto an incoming cab. The other guy gets scared and runs away. All the characters were Caucasian. This movie/series was before the time of Jessica Jones.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Do you recall what colour the woman's hair was?

Comment: Live action + recent + woman with super-strength + regular clothing + NY = Jessica Jones?  I don't remember a particular matching scene but it's been several years.

Comment: @DavidW my first thought too, just from the previews.

Comment: Can you be more precise about when you watched the series? The first season of *Jessica Jones* aired in 2015, which seems to fit with your timescale.

Comment: Warning, TV Tropes, but there might be something at https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MuggingTheMonster that I'm missing.

Comment: I assume you've now watched the Jessica Jones clip and are sure that's not the show you were thinking of?

Answer (score 17):

Possibly [*Jessica Jones* episode "The Sandwich That Saved Me"](https://ew.com/recap/marvels-jessica-jones-season-1-episode-5/)

> So Jessica has found her calling, and through that, we see the full scope of Kilgrave’s atrocity. As revealed toward the end of the episode, it was saving Malcolm from a group of muggers that alerted Kilgrave to Jessica’s abilities, what made her attractive to him. This is what makes Kilgrave just like any sex criminal. He takes the identity that she has struggled to find and reduced her to an object (hair, skin, and fashion sense) meant for his pleasure. The exchange is quiet and absolutely chilling and, in a single scene, establishes David Tennant as most terrifying villain in the Marvel universe.

Jessica does operate in New York City. Rewatching the scene in question, she does throw one of the muggers onto the roof of a car, where he rolls off of it, and then throws another one through what looks like a wooden shed before Kilgrave shows up.

### Jessica Jones trailer

The show initially ran on Netflix, but has since been moved to the Disney+ service. It is of ambiguous canonicity, like most of the Netflix shows (last I heard, the *Daredevil* show is going to be mostly canon).

Answer (score 3):

Not a perfect match, but perhaps [My Super Ex-Girlfriend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Super_Ex-Girlfriend) (2006)? Uma Thurman plays a superhero who becomes obsessed with Luke Wilson's everyman. Among other super powers, she has super strength, which she uses to fling a mugger, vehicles, and eventually a shark, among other things.